# Magento ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I started writing with magento. I have to do some ajax request for my own php-script located somewhere in local pull. The questions are:
 Where to store such php-scripts and with what address access them from ajax-request?

Comment: Is the script you want to request a module for Magento or just a free-standing script?

Comment: @jprofitt it's for Magento. It should return Cart data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a Controller that has an action that will handle the AJAX call. So if your module has a route of http://www.yoursite.com/yourscript, and you already have your IndexController, just put another action in there such as ajaxAction(). This action will simple print out the data you want to be consumed, and not render the rest of the page. Then you can point your AJAX call to http://www.yoursite.com/yourscript/index/ajax.

Comment: I have in local pull`/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php`. There, after `indexAction`, I've added `myownAction` with simple echo. What to do next?

Comment: As long as it's working, just keep going with getting whatever you're trying to display. Point your AJAX call to that address, and do what needs to be done with the return data.

Comment: I tried: `echo $this->getUrl('Checkout/Cart/showcart')`, I have `CartController` inside Checkout folder in code. There I have `showcartAction` function. But that url isn't valid :( What's wrong?

Comment: `getUrl()` provides you with an actual URL, not the contents of the page. If you want to render the contents you'll need to look at the template stuff. I haven't messed with getting data from the Cart, so I can't give any specifics.

Comment: You might want to take a look at some of the module tutorials that show how to set up proper routing. One of the best I've found (and still reference occasionally) is by Alan Storm http://alanstorm.com/category/magento